# Regex - match malformed hexadecimal string

Tags: regex, parsing, hex

I hope you're doing well.

I'm trying to make a regex for matching hexadecimal string in a message.

Sometimes the hex string is normal, always at format 0x + 40 hex characters like this : `0x0D6185e7481968D82B51F07191F8dAa721b2Db10`.

But sometimes, there is some spaces within it : `0x0 D6185 e7481968D82B51F07191F8 dAa721b2Db10`

And sometimes, this hex string is embedded in a message, so I can't use basic expression like `/([a-fA-F0-9x]{3,})/gm`, because in the following example

```
access
0x0D 6185e7481968 D82B51F07191F8d Aa721b2Db10
```

the `acce` part will also be selected when I'll try to reconstruct the hex string.

Generally the hex string is only on one line, but some other times on two or more lines like this :

```
access
0x0D6185e7481968 
D82B51F07191F8d
Aa721b2Db10
```

I can't figure out how I can solve this problem, so if someone could help me I would be grateful.

Thanks for reading,

Mateo

Comment: Try `/0x(?:\s*[a-fA-F0-9]){40}/g` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8JRl5b/1))

Comment: Was just writing the same thing as Wiktor https://regex101.com/r/sXyTga/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/0x(?:\s*[a-fA-F0-9]){40}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8JRl5b/2).

*Details*:

- `0x` - a `0x` fixed string
- `(?:\s*[a-fA-F0-9]){40}` - forty repetitions of zero or more whitespaces and then a hex char.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "0x0D6185e7481968D82B51F07191F8dAa721b2Db10\nBut sometimes, there is some spaces within it : 0x0 D6185 e7481968D82B51F07191F8 dAa721b2Db10\n\naccess\n0x0D6185e7481968 \nD82B51F07191F8d\nAa721b2Db10";
const regex = /0x(?:\s*[a-fA-F0-9]){40}/g;
console.log( text.match(regex) )
```

Comment: Thank you, it does the job exactly like I want !